# How to delete rows of a panda dataframe based on the count of occurences for specific column value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which records days of flying and days of maintenance. Values in 'Fly'

```
calendar = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date', 'Fly', 'Maint'])
```

Values in 'Fly' and 'Maint' equal 'Y' or 'N' for each element.

I would like to drop rows from the data set after the count of 'Y' values for either the 'Fly' or 'Maint' column reaches a specified value. It is occasionally helpful to consider the first X number of flying days or Y number of maintenance days, and those days do not align in a formulaic way with 'Date'.

I have a clumsy way to accomplish this with a while loop, but I sense there is a more efficient method:

```
while calendar[calendar['Fly'] == 'Y'].count()[0] > 100:
    
    calendar = calendar.drop(calendar.index[[-1]], axis=0)
```

I could also temporarily create a column that acts as a counter for 'Fly' then delete this column later. Would this generally be a preferable approach? Is there a cleaner way to avoid creating a new column?

Comment: Not totally sure I understand the logic: if there are 50 maintenance days, and 50 flying days, does that add up to 100 days in total? Or is that not enough days?

Comment: @Nick interesting remark, I hadn't envisioned it this way. I updated my answer to include this scenario

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity! I originally intended the question as @mozway first interpreted the problem, but the sum of 'Fly' OR 'Maint' could be valuable later. Thank you to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the rows until you reach the Nth Y in any column, you can use something like:

```
MAX = 3
m = (calendar[['Fly', 'Maint']].eq('Y') # check Y
     .cumsum()               # cumulative count 
     .lt(MAX).all(axis=1)    # keep below threshold 
     .shift(fill_value=True) # keep first row at threshold
     )

out = calendar[m]
```

Output:

```
   Date Fly Maint
0     0   Y     N
1     1   Y     Y
2     2   N     Y
3     3   Y     N # first row with a 3rd Y in any column
```

Used input:

```
   Date Fly Maint
0     0   Y     N
1     1   Y     Y
2     2   N     Y
3     3   Y     N
4     4   N     Y
5     5   N     N
6     6   Y     Y
7     7   N     Y
8     8   N     Y
9     9   N     N
```

Input with intermediates:

```
   Date Fly Maint  Fly_cumsum  Maint_cumsum      m
0     0   Y     N           1             0   True
1     1   Y     Y           2             1   True
2     2   N     Y           2             2   True
3     3   Y     N           3             2   True
4     4   N     Y           3             3  False
5     5   N     N           3             3  False
6     6   Y     Y           4             4  False
7     7   N     Y           4             5  False
8     8   N     Y           4             6  False
9     9   N     N           4             6  False
```

##### combined counts

If you rather want the **combined** count of rows with `Y` in either column, aggregate the booleans before the `cumsum`:

```
MAX = 3
m = (calendar[['Fly', 'Maint']].eq('Y')
     .any(axis=1)
     .cumsum()
     .lt(MAX)
     .shift(fill_value=True)
     )
```

Output:

```
   Date Fly Maint
0     0   Y     N
1     1   Y     Y
2     2   N     Y # 3rd "combined" Y
```

Intermediates:

```
   Date Fly Maint  count      m
0     0   Y     N      1   True
1     1   Y     Y      2   True
2     2   N     Y      3   True
3     3   Y     N      4  False
4     4   N     Y      5  False
5     5   N     N      5  False
6     6   Y     Y      6  False
7     7   N     Y      7  False
8     8   N     Y      8  False
9     9   N     N      8  False
```